# Translate CRC8 from C to Java

Tags: java, c, crc

I received a piece of code in C which calculates a CRC8-value of a byte array.
I need to translate it to Java.

Here the **C** Code:

```
CRC_POLYNOM = 0x9c;
CRC_PRESET = 0xFF;

unsigned int CRC = CRC_PRESET;
for (i = 0; i < Len; i++)
{
  crc ^= FRAME[i];
  for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
  {
    if (crc & 0x01)
        crc = (crc >> 1) ^ CRC_POLYNOM;
    else
        crc = (crc >> 1);
  }
}
```

What I have managed to do is this in **Java**:

```
public static long calculateCRC8(byte[] b, int len) {
  long crc = CRC_PRESET;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    crc ^= b[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      if ((crc & 0x01) == 0)
        crc = (crc >> 1) ^ CRC_POLYNOM;
      else
        crc = crc >> 1;
    }
  }
return crc;
}
```

For a sample byte-array:

```
byte[] b = new byte[] {1, 56, -23, 3, 0, 19, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 13, 8, -34, 7, 9, 42, 18, 26, -5, 54, 11, -94, -46, -128, 4, 48, 52, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 1, -32, -80, 0, 98, -5, 71, 0, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, -116, 1, 104, 2};
```

the **C** code returns **29**, my **Java** code returns **44** though.
What did I do wrong?

I think this is because of Java's signed-only datatypes, so how can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (crc & 0x01)
```

This tests if the lowest bit is set.

```
if ((crc & 0x01) == 0)
```

This tests if the bottom bit is *clear.*

You should also use an unsigned right shift in the Java code (i.e. `>>>` instead of `>>`, in two places), and mask the result with `0xff` before returning it.

**EDIT** And finally you need to change this:

```
crc ^= b[i];
```

to this:

```
crc ^= b[i] & 0xff;
```

However you should really throw it all away and look up the table driven method. It is eight times as fast as this.

***EDIT 2*** Table-driven version, revised so as to implement `java.util.zip.Checksum:`

```
public class CRC8 implements Checksum
{
    private final short init;
    private final short[]   crcTable = new short[256];
    private short   value;

    /**
     * Construct a CRC8 specifying the polynomial and initial value.
     * @param polynomial Polynomial, typically one of the POLYNOMIAL_* constants.
     * @param init Initial value, typically either 0xff or zero.
     */
    public CRC8(int polynomial, short init)
    {
        this.value = this.init = init;
        for (int dividend = 0; dividend < 256; dividend++)
        {
            int remainder = dividend ;//<< 8;
            for (int bit = 0; bit < 8; ++bit)
                if ((remainder & 0x01) != 0)
                    remainder = (remainder >>> 1) ^ polynomial;
                else
                    remainder >>>= 1;
            crcTable[dividend] = (short)remainder;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(byte[] buffer, int offset, int len)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            int data = buffer[offset+i] ^ value;
            value = (short)(crcTable[data & 0xff] ^ (value << 8));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates the current checksum with the specified array of bytes.
     * Equivalent to calling <code>update(buffer, 0, buffer.length)</code>.
     * @param buffer the byte array to update the checksum with
     */
    public void update(byte[] buffer)
    {
        update(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(int b)
    {
        update(new byte[]{(byte)b}, 0, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public long getValue()
    {
        return value & 0xff;
    }

    @Override
    public void reset()
    {
        value = init;
    }

    public static void  main(String[] args)
    {
        final int   CRC_POLYNOM = 0x9C;
        final byte  CRC_INITIAL = (byte)0xFF;

        final byte[]    data = {1, 56, -23, 3, 0, 19, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 13, 8, -34, 7, 9, 42, 18, 26, -5, 54, 11, -94, -46, -128, 4, 48, 52, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 1, -32, -80, 0, 98, -5, 71, 0, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, -116, 1, 104, 2};
        CRC8    crc8 = new CRC8(CRC_POLYNOM, CRC_INITIAL);
        crc8.update(data,0,data.length);
        System.out.println("Test successful:\t"+(crc8.getValue() == 29));
    }
}
```

Comment: `if ((crc & 0x01) == 0x01)

          crc = ((crc >> 1) & 0xff) ^ CRC_POLYNOM;

        else

          crc = (crc >> 1) & 0xff;

      }
    }

    return crc;`

I have masked the triple right shifts with 0xff. It now returns 75.

Comment: @AlexanderCiesielski Keep watching, I'll post the table code, but probably not tonight, it's now 10:30pm my time.

Comment: replace 'update(int)' to:     public void update(int b) {
        update(ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.BYTES).putInt(b).array(), 0, Integer.BYTES);
    }

Comment: I implemented this version but didn't manage to get the same results as all online CRC8 calculators. Did I miss something ?

Comment: I have to calculate a CRC8 defined as polynomial=0xEA, init=0x000, MSB first (not reversed) and no final XOR.

Answer (score 2):

Your "^" actually already points like an arrow to the part where the mistake is

the equivalent of

```
if (crc & 0x01)
```

in Java would be (as java needs boolean expressions in if)

```
if ((crc & 0x01) != 0)
```

or

```
if ((crc & 0x01) == 0x01)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But now it returns 47 instead of 44.

Comment: With all the corrections I mentioned in my answer? In all four places? And is 'crc' initialized to CRC_PRESET in the C code?

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's the >>> instead of >> as in EJPs simultaneous answer. The semantics here are different, because java doesn't have "unsigned" types as C does. It sometimes is also annyoing when casting to a smaller type.

Comment: Getting 75 now when I switched to >>> and masking it with 0xff

Comment: @AlexanderCiesielski If you're commenting on my answer please comment under my answer.

Comment: Hmmm - OK - getting 29 now. I guess one information was missing: FRAME is of type "unsigned char", right? So instead of `crc ^= FRAME[i]` we would have `crc = (crc ^ FRAME[i]) & 0xFF` instead - and then it doesn't matter if you use `>>` or `>>>`... better always post all the needed code to compile the program!

Answer (score 1):

I created a complete/standalone C program of your question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CRC_POLYNOM 0x9c
#define CRC_PRESET 0xFF

int main() {
    unsigned int crc = CRC_PRESET;
    unsigned char FRAME[] = {1, 56, -23, 3, 0, 19, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 13, 8, -34, 7, 9, 42, 18, 26, -5, 54, 11, -94, -46, -128, 4, 48, 52, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 1, -32, -80, 0, 98, -5, 71, 0, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, -116, 1, 104, 2};
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(FRAME); i++) {
        crc ^= FRAME[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if(crc & 0x01) {
                crc = (crc >> 1) ^ CRC_POLYNOM;
            } else {
                crc = (crc >> 1);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%u\n", crc);
    return 0;
}
```

Here the equivalent Java code automatically created on https://www.mtsystems.com:

```
package demo;

public class DemoTranslation {
    public final static int CRC_POLYNOM = 0x9c;

    public final static int CRC_PRESET = 0xFF;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int crc_U = CRC_PRESET;
        byte[] frame_U = {1, 56, -23, 3, 0, 19, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 13, 8, -34, 7, 9, 42, 18, 26, -5, 54, 11, -94, -46, -128, 4, 48, 52, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 1, -32, -80, 0, 98, -5, 71, 0, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, -116, 1, 104, 2};
        for(int i = 0; i < frame_U.length; i++) {
            crc_U ^= Byte.toUnsignedInt(frame_U[i]);
            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                if((crc_U & 0x01) != 0) {
                    crc_U = (crc_U >>> 1) ^ CRC_POLYNOM;
                } else {
                    crc_U = (crc_U >>> 1);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Integer.toUnsignedString(crc_U));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the accepted answer, I could not get checksums that matched online CRC8 calculators such as http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html.

So I translated https://github.com/RobTillaart/CRC/blob/master/CRC8.cpp from C to Java and tested successfully with various initial values and Polynomials:

```
    final byte[] data = {0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39}; // sample data
    final byte INIT_VAL = (byte) 0x00;
    final byte POLY = 0x07;

    int _crc = INIT_VAL;
    for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        int value = data[j];
        _crc = _crc ^ value;
        for (int i = 8; i > 0; i--) {
            if ((_crc & (1 << 7)) > 0) {
                _crc <<= 1;
                _crc ^= POLY;
            } else {
                _crc <<= 1;
            }
        }
    }
    result = (_crc & 0xff);
```