# CRC8 algorithm computation

Tags: java, crc

I have a specific tuning of CRC8 to implement in Java but I didn't figure out how to tune "googleized" algorithms to fit my need.

I have reference data put in JUnit tests to assure my computation matches with the equipment I'm interfaced with.

It is defined as :

- polynomial 0xEA
- initial data 0x0000
- MSB first (not reversed)
- No final XOR

The first two parameters are self-explanatory but I had a hard time implementing the other ones.

Edit : some reference data :
0x80000003000000000000 -> 0xB0

0x80000003FC0000FF80D8 -> 0xF2

0x80000003FE00000038E4 -> 0x5E

0x80000003075555FFC71C -> 0x58

0x8000000302000000E38E -> 0x3A

Algorithm used as a work basis : accepted answer here : [Translate CRC8 from C to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284556/translate-crc8-from-c-to-java)

Comment: Polynomial 0xEA would be a 7 bit CRC shifted left 1 bit.  MSB first is how most processors would load a byte from memory, and a left shifting CRC is used. No final XOR means once the CRC (remainder) is calculated, you don't XOR some constant value, such as 0xFF to the CRC.

Comment: @Zofren Do you have any examples of message and their CRC8s?

Comment: I added some ref data and known computed CRC8.

Comment: @MarkAdler for the notification :)

Comment: The check values in your reference data cannot be produced by _any_ CRC-8.

Comment: @MarkAdler Values are from the constructor simulator. And description of this field is from their reference interface description document. What is problematic with the reference data and the computed values ?

Comment: Can you provide links to those?

Comment: See the problem in my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the polynomial was provided to you using Koopman's notation, which removes the least significant one and shifts down one in order to be able represent a degree *n* polynomial in *n* bits. The low bit of a CRC polynomial is always one. If it were not, it would generate a CRC that always has a zero in the low bit, and so would not actually be an *n* bit CRC (as noted by rcgldr in the comments).

Then the polynomial represented more conventionally is `0xd5`, where instead the high one bit (the *x<sup>n</sup>* term) is dropped. That, along with the rest of your CRC description, is in fact a known 8-bit CRC, [CRC-8/DVB-S2](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/all.htm#crc.cat.crc-8-dvb-s2). (See link for sources.)

However that CRC-8 does not match your example message CRCs. You have the wrong description, or there is something wrong with your extraction of messages and associated CRCs. What is the equipment, where did you get the CRC description from, and where did you get the reference data from?

Comment: I got the description from the official interface document from the constructor. And I got the reference data from their simulator.